# Can't make asset precompile before pushing to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, precompile

I need to make it to make my jQuery working on Heroku.

Here is my console:

```
    $ rake assets:precompile
    c:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe c:/Ruby192/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
  rake aborted!
  Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
  Tasks: TOP => environment
  (See full trace by running task with --trace)
   rake aborted!
  Command failed with status (1): [c:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe c:/Ruby192/bin/rak...]
  Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
  (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When I try do run:

```
     $ assets:precompile
     sh: assets:precompile: command not found
```

**EDITED:**
Also I added this line to application.rb:

```
      config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Comment: This is failing because your database credentials are not correct for the `production` environment. Secondly, `assets:precompile` should be `rake assets:precompile` like the first time you used it

Comment: Correct production section in database config. I think, that the simplest solution is to copy development config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mentioned wrong username and password of mysql. Some gems which need database access for assets:precompile.